# Displaying results from search

Tags: java, json, gson

I have been playing with GSON and JSON to complete a search and display the results. I have this piece of code but I can't get it to display the results:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
    String search = "food pantries in Dallas";
    String charset = "UTF-8";

    URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset));
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);


    // Show title and URL of 1st result.
    System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getTitle());
    System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl());
    System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults());

}
```

UPDATE:

I am able to get some results using the search and it is displayed list this:

```
<b>Food Pantries</b> | Soup Kitchens | <b>Food Banks</b>
http://www.foodpantries.org/
[Result[url:http://www.foodpantries.org/,title:<b>Food Pantries</b> | Soup Kitchens | <b>Food Banks</b>], Result[url:http://feedingamerica.org/foodbank-results.aspx,title:Find a Local <b>Food Bank</b> | Feeding America], Result[url:http://www.foodbanknyc.org/,title:<b>Food Bank</b> for New York City], Result[url:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_bank,title:<b>Food bank</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia]]
```

I am trying to create clean list that will display this results showing just the Websites and maybe some more information.

I was thinking about using Jsoup but was not sure how to integrate the two. Any advice?

Thanks,

Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard, assuming your GoogleResults class is a java bean that matches the attributes in the response, you just need to properly encode your search query:

Change:

```
URL url = new URL(google + search);
```

to:

```
URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search,"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the code and I am getting some answers. I have updated the code above. Now I am getting some results and I need to format the results to display a nice list. I will post the code and the answer below.